# Script for gitlab data by users

Tags: python, github, github-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlx1I.png)

In the github searchbox, if i am searching as below, i am getting perfect result.

```
is:pr archived:false is:closed base:master base:main merged:>=2023-01-01 author:author1 
is:pr archived:false is:closed base:master base:main merged:>=2023-01-01 author:author2
..
..
..
is:pr archived:false is:closed base:master base:main merged:>=2023-01-01 author:author20
```

How i can generate it using a script preferably in python or shell where i pass a list of username and get count of above query for all users. (not able to use githum api for this.)

Comment: But your script, in python or shell, would have to call the GitHub API anyway, no?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.